# Why are some Stack Overflow questions overhyped?

Tags: discussion, popularity

Why are some Stack Overflow questions overhyped? I mean when I look into the home page, most of the newly created questions has like 10 views in first 5 min. But then there are some questions which has like billion views after minute of publishing? How is that possible? Is it only cause of the content, or is it something else?

Comment: *"But then there are some questions which has like billion views after minute of publishing?"* Can you give an example of a question that has had billions of views and was posted today (UTC)? I assume one you've seen today prompted you to ask this .

Comment: If you want to use the word "hype", you are probably doing it wrong. Hype and meme are quickly replacing a sizeable chunk of the dictionary and it's a shame because the diversity in wording allows for nuance. "Popular" is the word you were looking for here. Hype implies that other people are just following others like lemmings, popularity allows for people to be making their own decisions in the process. It's a nicer thing to assume all around, you can only gain by doing so.

Comment: @Gimby: Except that [lemmings don't actually do that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yNtpWSRF6o8) (mostly [made up by Disney in 1958](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1iqVsbwNA50) in *[White Wilderness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Wilderness_(film))*).

Comment: @PeterMortensen well I was more referring to the legendary video game series of the same name, but I might have assumed too much when making that reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are not *overhyped*. If you look for example on this question:
[Resolve "Property does not exist on type 'Vue'" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45555089/resolve-property-does-not-exist-on-type-vue-error) which is in 5 min ago section, you can see it's actually posted like 4 years ago. The date which you see on home page, is mostly the date of latest update, answer, comment, etc...